# How to load from a folder without combining files

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to load several csv files from a folder that aren't connected.
Its not allowing me to load them without combining them.

Get Data > File > Folder

When they load it automatically tries to combine them which creates NULLs in one of the file rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get data from folder, it will combine all file into one table. To load each file into it's own table, you should get data from a Text/CSV file instead and import each of the files you want.

Comment: So i'll have to import csv files individually? What if I have 20 csv files?

Comment: You will have to import them one by one. In case you want to avoid combining files. If combining isn't a problem, them get data from folder. The row should be in some of the files, so you will get it anyway. You can filter out the unwanted rows after importing the data.

Comment: you mean have a common row on all files to have a common denominator to combine files on and then remove that specific row? @Andrey Nikolov

Comment: No, I mean the row with NULLs which bothers you.